# how to create multiple templates in Gatsby.js

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I was trying to make two template for my projects details and blog post pages, but due to my lake of experience with Graphql & Gatsby I have managed to make it work for my projects, project details and blog posts but I have a bug which I couldn't find on my blog posts article template makes it not working??

here is my .md front matter

```
---
title: The Kimo-Coffee
stack: HTML & CSS
slug: the-kimo-coffee
date: 2022/01/03
key: projects
thumb: ../images/thumbs/coffee.png
featuredImg: ../images/featured/coffee-banner.png
---
```

and this is my blog page code (that's working fine)

```
import { graphql, Link } from "gatsby"
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../../components/Layout"
import * as styles from "../../styles/blog.module.css"
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"

const posts = ({ data }) => {
  const posts = data.articles.nodes
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={styles.blog}>
        <h2>Blog Posts</h2>

        {posts.map(post => (
          <Link to={"/blog/" + post.frontmatter.slug} key={post.id}>
            <div className={styles.posts}>
              <GatsbyImage
                image={getImage(post.frontmatter.thumb)}
                alt={post.frontmatter.title}
              />
              <h3 className={styles.title}>{post.frontmatter.title}</h3>
              <p className={styles.date}>{post.frontmatter.date}</p>
              <p className={styles.stack}>{post.frontmatter.stack}</p>
              <p className={styles.description}>
                {post.frontmatter.description}
              </p>
            </div>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default posts

export const query = graphql`
  query BlogPosts {
    articles: allMdx(
      filter: { frontmatter: { key: { eq: "article" } } }
      sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }
    ) {
      nodes {
        excerpt
        slug
        frontmatter {
          key
          date
          title
          stack
          description
          thumb {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(placeholder: BLURRED, layout: FULL_WIDTH)
            }
          }
        }
        id
      }
    }
  }
`
```

here is my blog post details (which is not working)

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql, Link } from "gatsby"
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx"
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import * as styles from "../styles/blog-details.module.css"

const blogPosts = ({ data, pageContext }) => {
  const { body } = data.article
  const { title, date, stack, featuredImg } = data.article.frontmatter
  const { previous, next } = pageContext

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={styles.details}>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <p>{date}</p>
        <p>{stack}</p>
        <div className={styles.featured}>
          <GatsbyImage
            image={getImage(featuredImg.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData)}
            alt={title}
          />
        </div>
        <article className={styles.body}>
          <MDXRenderer>{body}</MDXRenderer>
        </article>
        <React.Fragment>
          {previous && (
            <Link to={previous.frontmatter.slug}>
              <button>{previous.frontmatter.title}</button>
            </Link>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
        <React.Fragment>
          {next && (
            <Link to={next.frontmatter.slug}>
              <button>{next.frontmatter.title}</button>
            </Link>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default blogPosts

export const query = graphql`
  query BlogDetails($slug: String) {
    article: mdx(frontmatter: { slug: { eq: $slug }, key: { eq: "article" } }) {
      body
      frontmatter {
        slug
        key
        title
        date
        stack
        featuredImg {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData(placeholder: BLURRED, layout: FULL_WIDTH)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

and last this is my code for gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require("path")
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, actions }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  if (node.internal.type === `Mdx`) {
    const slug = createFilePath({ node, getNode, basePath: `pages` })
    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: slug,
    })
  }
}

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const results1 = await graphql(`
    query content {
      allMdx(filter: { frontmatter: { key: { eq: "projects" } } }) {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            slug
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const results2 = await graphql(`
    query content {
      allMdx(filter: { frontmatter: { key: { eq: "article" } } }) {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            slug
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const projectTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/project-details.js`)
  const blogTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/blog-details.js`)
  if (results1.errors || results2.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
    return
  }

  const posts = results2.data.allMdx.nodes

  posts.forEach((post, index) => {
    const previous = index === post.length - 1 ? null : post[index + 1]
    const next = index === 0 ? null : posts[index - 1]
    createPage({
      path: `/blog/${post.frontmatter.slug}`,
      component: blogTemplate,
      context: {
        slug: post.frontmatter.slug,
        previous,
        next,
      },
    })
  })

  results1.data.allMdx.nodes.forEach(node => {
    createPage({
      path: `/projects/${node.frontmatter.slug}`,
      component: projectTemplate,
      context: { slug: node.frontmatter.slug },
    })
  })
}
```

sorry if my code is ugly, I'm pretty new to programming and i started with Gatsby since it makes me feel optimistic after learning javascript and react :)

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"? Is the query working on the GraphiQL playground? (returning all the fields etc)

Comment: I mean that when I click on blog link it works fine leads me to the blog page, then when I click any blog post it gives me an error "There's not a page or function yet at /blog/undefined"

Comment: the Graphql query is working fine on GraphiQL playground, also I'm not getting any error in the terminal on my IDE while developing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things weird in your code that shouldn't be working despite your said it does.

In React, all components must be capitalized, otherwise, React will interpret them as HTML elements, and because normally a component name doesn't match an HTML tag, it will break because it won't exist.

In your case, both templates must be renamed to:

```
const Posts = ({ data }) => {}
```

And:

```
const BlogPosts = ({ data, pageContext }) => {}
```

The prompted error:

> "There's not a page or function yet at /blog/undefined"

This means that the template is not valid because there is not a valid function template. Once capitalized, the issue should be gone.

In addition, double-check the markdowns to ensure that you have a `slug` field in all of them.

You can also enter to `localhost:8000/404` which in development, displays a list of all generated pages. You can check there if all the posts are being created correctly. If so, the issue is in your template. Otherwise, it's in your page generation.

Your issue is in the GraphQL query of the `BlogPosts`, where the link to the article is not properly set. You have defined a query like:

```
  query BlogPosts {
    articles: allMdx(
      filter: { frontmatter: { key: { eq: "article" } } }
      sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }
    ) {
      nodes {
        excerpt
        slug # <-- here's the issue
        frontmatter {
          key
          date
          title
          stack
          description
          thumb {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(placeholder: BLURRED, layout: FULL_WIDTH)
            }
          }
        }
        id
      }
    }
  }
```

Where the `slug` is directly under `nodes` node. At the same time, you are linking the slug as it was a child of the `frontmatter` at:

```
<Link to={"/blog/" + post.frontmatter.slug} key={post.id}>
```

Which results in `blog/undefined` path. You can check the path just hovering the link and seeing where is it pointing.

Ensure where it should be the slug field according to your data structure. I'd say that it should be inside the `frontmatter`:

```
        frontmatter {
          slug # <-- add it here
          key
          date
          title
          stack
          description
          thumb {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(placeholder: BLURRED, layout: FULL_WIDTH)
            }
          }
        }
```

Alternatively, just change the `Link` structure like:

```
<Link to={"/blog/" + post.slug} key={post.id}>
```

### TL:DR

Because of:

```
createNodeField({
  node,
  name: `slug`,
  value: slug,
})
```

You are creating a `slug` based on the filename, which is being inserted as a `node` child, that's why the query was working but the references to that wasn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot for catching my errors, I really appreciate Your kind explanations , I have corrected them and then checked the 404 page and all pages i created included my posts are available there and the template is working when i clicked the post from the 404 page, but still not working and showing same undefined error when i click a post on the blog page, all template are working fine except the one for posts which i show previously with a comment of (not working), is there any hints what could be the issue on this template causing this error!?

Comment: Are the posts pages being created correctly? Is there  a `blog/slugOfPost`?

Comment: yes it does show the post and here an example of the blog post for the first post  `http://localhost:8000/blog/the-first-article` that's when i clicked it from the 404 page display of links !?

Comment: In that case, `<Link to={"/blog/" + post.frontmatter.slug} key={post.id}>` the `post.frontmatter.slug` is `undefined`. Check the `post` data

Comment: I spot your mistake. Your `slug` in the GraphQL query is defined outside the `frontmatter` while it's invoked inside. I will update the answer

Comment: I can not dream more oh, finally it's working :), really you are amazing, thank you for you kind help and detailed explanation and I really appreciate you effort and time, that's my first ever Gatsby project, say it's my first ever web dev. project, promise I will get better in my next Gatsby project :)

Comment: Thanks for your words @KarimElnemr I really appreciate it. If the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvoting the answer to close the topic.